# Kendo multi select pass current typing text as a parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

```
 $("#claim").kendoMultiSelect({
        dataTextField: "Text",
        dataValueField: "Code",
        autoBind: false,
        minlength: 5,
        deselect: onDeselect,
        select: onSelect,
       //dataSource: listdata,
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: "/Home/GetAllClaimsOfTeams?text_para=<**PASS_CURRENT_TEXT**>"
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I pass current text to the server side as a parameter to the read method?

Comment: [this](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/combobox/serverfiltering) might help - something like `transport: { read: "...", data: { text_para: $("#claim").data("kendoComboBox").value() }`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function in the 'filtering' event and rewrite the read URL with the value of what are you currently typing:

```
$("#claim").kendoMultiSelect({
        dataTextField: "Text",
        dataValueField: "Code",
        autoBind: false,
        minlength: 5,
        deselect: onDeselect,
        select: onSelect,
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: "/Home/GetAllClaimsOfTeams?text_para=<**PASS_CURRENT_TEXT**>"
            }
        },
        filtering:function(e){
          this.options.dataSource.transport.read = "/Home/GetAllClaimsOfTeams?text_para= " + e.filter.value;
        }
    });
```